# Disallow file edit not preventing plugin install

Tags: security

I have a little demo site (admin details are listed publicly), and I've configured the `wp-config.php` to disallow file edits, so in theory no one can install a theme / plugin.

```php
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );
```

Yet lately I've noticed strange plugins & themes being installed on my demo site. I can see in the apache logs that they've been trying to access `plugin-install.php` but failing with a 500 error.

The folder permissions are `755` on both plugins & themes, so the files can execute but only the user has write access.

Does anyone know how they might be doing it / where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you would post a couple of the full log entries it would help. I suspect this is a bot trying to get access to the site-- just a guess.

Comment: Seems my host only keeps the apache logs for a day :|

Comment: Basically, requests were made to plugin-install.php and failing with 500 error... yet the plugins made it through. Could another plugin allow them to install a plugin on WordPress?

Comment: Your description worries me, especially the part about the plugin making it through. It sounds like you have a security problem but I don't know that it can be solved in this venue.

Comment: Perhaps your WordPress security are being overwritten from your cPanel or your panel (if not using cPanel). This sounds more like a problem with your hosting company. Why not contact them and explain the issue?

Comment: The behaviour is indicatory of a compromised website. Check your site for malwares or hacks.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the site to a subsite on a multi-site instance, you can then have an approved list of plugins and themes. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740816/how-to-install-plugins-on-a-per-site-basis-on-a-multisite-network) might help more.

You could also create a new user type that does not have access to the plugins/themes areas and only publish those details.